# Docker swarm - log to rsyslog container

Tags: logging, docker, syslog, docker-swarm, rsyslog

I have a docker swarm with 6 services that I want to have logging to one central logging container.
I have this working in my dev environment (non swarm) - see the docker-compose file below.

When I try to transition the configuration from the dev env to my swarm prod env, it fails.

first I raise the log service:

```
docker service create --replicas 1 \
--name logserver \
--network phototankswarm \
--constraint=node.hostname==pi2 \
-p localhost:5514:514 \
kaninfod/pt-syslog
```

This runs up nicely.

Then one of the services (e.g a redis):

```
docker service create --replicas 1 \
--name redis \
--network phototankswarm \
--constraint=node.hostname==pi1 \
--log-driver=syslog \
--log-opt syslog-facility="daemon" \
--log-opt tag="rails" \
--log-opt syslog-address="tcp://localhost:5514" \
-p 6379:6379 \
armhf/redis
```

And this fails with:

```
starting container failed: Failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp [::1]:5514: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I had problems with the syslog-address when setting up the dev env...I find it strange that I have to use the localhost rather than the docker dns name of the log container...but en dev it works with localhost.

This is the compose file I use for my dev env:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - api
      - syslog
    ports:
      - "80:8080"

    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-facility: "daemon"
        tag: "nginx"
        syslog-address: "tcp://localhost:5514"
    networks:
      - phototankswarm
    env_file: .env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./frontend/public:/www

  db:
    image: mysql
    env_file: .env.dev
    depends_on:
      - syslog
    networks:
      - phototankswarm
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./sql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-facility: "daemon"
        tag: "mysql"
        syslog-address: "tcp://localhost:5514"

  redis:
    image: redis
    depends_on:
      - syslog
    networks:
      - phototankswarm
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-facility: "daemon"
        tag: "redis"
        syslog-address: "tcp://localhost:5514"

  api:
    image: pt-rails
    env_file: .env.dev
    networks:
      - phototankswarm
    command: >
      sh -c '
      bundle exec sidekiq -d && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
      '
    volumes:
      - /Users/martinhinge/Pictures/docker/phototank:/media/phototank
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - syslog
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-facility: "daemon"
        tag: "rails"
        syslog-address: "tcp://localhost:5514"

  syslog:
    image: syslog
    ports:
      - "localhost:5514:514"
    networks:
      - phototankswarm
    volumes:
      - /tmp:/var/log/syslog

networks:
  phototankswarm:
```

**EDIT**

running `$ docker run -it --rm --net container:dac082edcd6f hypriot/rpi-alpine-scratch netstat -lnt` yields:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:35314        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::514                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: please can you try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Have tried it and no differens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
--log-opt syslog-address="tcp://localhost:5514" \
```

to:

```
--log-opt syslog-address="tcp://logserver:514" \
```

Networking between containers will use DNS based discovery as long as they are running on the same network. Localhost inside a container is a separate namespace from the localhost on the docker host outside the container, so the container will not see ports published on the docker host with the loopback address. You may be able to connect to your docker host by it's hostname instead of localhost. However, container-to-container networking is more portable.

The only reason I can think that this would work in dev with localhost is if your service is using the host network mode, rather than being connected to the overlay network.

Comment: @MBitch I agree that container - container is the way to go, thus my remark about localhost. I tried your suggestion and got the exact same result :-( So it must be something else..

Comment: Is `phototankswarm` an overlay network? Are there any firewalls (including iptables) limiting connections between hosts? Can you ping by container name to see if DNS and IP are working?

Comment: Yes it's an overlay network, no firewalls and yes I can ping from redis to logserver using container names....

Comment: From pi2, find the container id of logserver and run: `docker run -it --rm --net container:$container_id nicolaka/netshoot netstat -lnt`

Comment: it's a raspberry pi...can't use the image. But I get you...have a look at the edit at the bottom of my question above

Comment: found [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26011) saying: _Logging is initialized on the daemon, not inside the container, which means container networking has no bearing on how the daemon can connect to some logging service.
Is that address reachable from the host?_ which is propably why localhost works and might be preferred.

Comment: Your production environment is running on raspberry pi's? O.o

Comment: It's not that kind of production - it's a scaled down test setup...Should still work though